# Android list view Base adapter getView fire multiple times?

Tags: android, android-layout

**This is my XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/preview_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/socialbottom"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Preview"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/close_preview_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/close_btn" />
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_below="@+id/preview_header">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/preview_dialog_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    style="@style/Space"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/preview_add_more_btn"></View>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/preview_add_more_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/empty_view1"
    android:background="@color/content_text"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/plus_icon"
    android:drawablePadding="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="300dp"
    android:text="@string/add_more"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/empty_view1"
    style="@style/Space"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer_preview"></View>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/preview_input_timeline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/acticty_textbox"
        android:hint="What&apos;s up, admin?"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="8dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/preview_post_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/preview_input_timeline"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/savebox"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Post"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is JAVA**

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.preview_list_view, null);
        ImageButton removeBtn = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.remove_preview);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.preview_image);
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.preview_video);
        Log.e("video sizzzessssssss", String.valueOf(imagesList.size()));
        if (SocialActivity.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE == previewType) {
            videoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String path = imagesList.get(position);
            File imgFile = new File(path);
            if (imgFile.exists()) {
                // Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                //  imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                Bitmap d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), imgFile.getAbsolutePath()).getBitmap();
                int nh = (int) (d.getHeight() * (512.0 / d.getWidth()));
                Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(d, 512, nh, true);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(scaled);

            }


        } else {
            imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            videoView.setVideoPath(imagesList.get(position));
            MediaController mediaControls = new MediaController(SocialActivity.socialActivity);
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaControls);
            videoView.start();
            videoView.pause();
            Log.e("path video", imagesList.get(position));
        }
        removeBtn.setOnClickListener(new ListCustomClickEvents(callback, position));

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I don't know what is your question.

Comment: getview methods fire multiple times@ssh

Comment: @kathir for each visible item on the screen `getView` method will be called two times. It happens due to inner caching mechanism of ListView. So this is a normal situation.

Comment: @kathir you need just check `if(convertView==null) convertView = inflate...` to solve this question.

Comment: @kathir and close this question. This is the one of the most often question of stackoverflow in Android development.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `setTag()` and `getTag()`

like these

```
public class ViewHolder {


       //Declare yours all component here

        // like below example
        private ImageView profile_iv;
        private TextView name_tv;


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

///Firstly check the convertView is null or not like below  
        final ViewHolder _viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {


            _viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater _layInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = _layInflater.inflate(R.layout.connection_friend_item, null);

       ///Finds yours layout items id here like below example

            _viewHolder.profile_iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_iv);
            _viewHolder.name_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_tv);



            convertView.setTag(_viewHolder);


        } else {
            _viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

       ////Set the data in the layout's item as below

        _viewHolder.name_tv.setText(imagesList.get(position));
        _viewHolder.profile_iv.setImageBitmap(imagesList.get(position));


        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use View Holder design pattern enables you to access each list item view without the need for the look up, saving valuable processor cycles. Specifically, it avoids frequent call of findViewById() during ListView scrolling, and that will make it smooth.

Refer below code for Demo:

```
 public static class ViewHolder{

        public TextView aliasTextView;
        public TextView numTextView;
        public TextView statusTextView;
        public RelativeLayout mainLayout;
        public NetworkImageView _profileImageView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        DisputeListBean bean = _ArrayList.get(position);

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dispute_row, null,false);
            holder.mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
            holder.aliasTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            holder.statusTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.user_status);
            holder._profileImageView = (NetworkImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
            v.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.aliasTextView.setText(bean.getAlias_name().toUpperCase());

        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't give listview's height as wrap_content. When you the height as wrap_content, the listview will first populate few list items to determine the actual height of the listview

Answer (score 0):

Due to inner caching mechanism in `ListView`, Android will be fire two times `getView` method for each visible item. It happens only for first time, when you open Activity/Fragment/View that contains a ListView. For more information refer to google with `ScrapViews ListView` request.

To solve your problem you need just check

```
if(convertView == null)
    convertView = inflate...
```

or use ViewHolder pattern from Google.